# How do i vertically center that sidemenu in the left?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to vertically centre this side menu on the left, but I can't. Help? Possibly with flex display

```
#side-menu {
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
right: -40px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
margin: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

https://imgur.com/a/xjaeHZ3

Answer (score 0):

Try using justify-content to do it. it does the magic you're looking for when using flex.

```
Justify-content: center
```